# How can I arrange an array from 500 down to 1 in an array? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to arrange and printout an array starting at 500 and stopping at 1,
I have tried this with the following code, but this will printout starting from 1 and going up to 500:

```
int [] aftel = new int [501];
for (int teller3 = 500; teller3 > 0; teller3--){
       aftel[teller3] = teller3;
    }
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aftel));
```

However using the following code, the array will printout the correct way, but I'm trying to arrange the array fully before printing out values:

```
int [] aftel = new int [501];
for (int teller2 = 1; teller2 <= 500; teller2++){
        optel500[teller2] = teller2;
        System.out.print(optel500[teller2]+" ");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first loop, you're using `teller3` as both an index *and* a value. That means that index 500 will have the value 500, which is the opposite of what you want.

You're also making a bit of confusion with the array size.

The correct way to do this would be to either do the loop straight and subtract the value from 500

```
int [] aftel = new int [500];
for (int teller3 = 0; teller3 < 500; teller3++){
    aftel500[teller3] = (500 - teller3) + 1;
}
```

Or do the same to the array index

```
int [] aftel = new int [500];
for (int teller3 = 500; teller3 > 0; teller3--){
   aftel[500 - teller3] = teller3;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
int[] array = IntStream
        .range(0, 500) // get a stream of [0, 499]
        .map(i -> 500 - i) // map it to [500, 1]
        .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are filling the array backwards. Starting from the most significant index down to index 1. In order to achieve the result you should fill from index 1 to the most significant one.

Introducing another variable like `index = 1` and using it in such manner will fix the issue:

```
int [] aftel = new int [501];
int index = 1;

for (int teller3 = 500; teller3 > 0; teller3--){
    aftel[index] = teller3;
    index++;
}
```

and alternatively the one liner for loop:

```
int [] aftel = new int [501];

for (int teller3 = 500, index = 1; teller3 > 0; teller3--, index++){
    aftel[index] = teller3;
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aftel));
```

Comment: Java is 0 based. he shouldn't start at index 1, he should start at index 0

Comment: Check OPs requirement first. He wants to fill the closed index range [1, 500].

Comment: he is talking about the values 1 to 500. As for his code where he goes with those indices, has it occurred to you he doesn't realize Java is 0 based? there is no mention in the post the indices are supposed to be 1 to 500

Comment: Well in the initial array classes we had the advice of the teacher was to use N+1 sized arrays and then use indexes in [1, N]. So this is a valid case in such perspective. The logic used in the quoted code is quite close to that so I guess he is a novice in the arrays filed. Also he sees the additional number(0) at the beginning of the output but did not mention that as a problem rather then order of the elements.

Comment: OK. Now I am curious. did your teacher give you a specific reason as to why use [1, N] as indices for a [N+1] sized array? besides the fact that in complex algorithms this can cause serious validation problems, I can't think of any upside of ignoring the specifications of the language

Comment: It is done in the matter of understanding the array as a data structures a bit easier. Few lectures later they will let you play with indexes and test your understanding of the 0 based arrays (not only java -> it was a C class indeed). Also this was in the university while I knew arrays pretty well from high school classes and this was strange for me either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set 500 on position 500, but you must set 500 on position 0.
This should work:

```
int [] aftel = new int [501];
for (int teller3 = 500; teller3 > 0; teller3--){
       aftel[500 - teller3] = teller3;
    }
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aftel));
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
int noOfElements = 500;
int[] array = new int[noOfElements];

for (int i = 0; i < noOfElements; i++){
    array[i] = noOfElements - i;
}

for(int a : array){
    System.out.println(a);
}
```